# updating json response salesforce

Tags: metadata-api, json, rest, metadata

```
{ “FirstName” : “Foo”, 
  “LastName” : “Bar”, 
  “Address” : 
       { “city” : “Pune”, “state” : “Maharashtra”, “country” : “India” } 
}
```

My issues is to fetch the "city" value from the above json format ,and update it to "USA"(say).

what could be the possible solution?
The above json format I am getting by using response.getbody().

Like I am using

```
Map<string,object> objmap= (Map<string,object>)json.deserializeuntype(response.getbody());
system.debug(objmap.get('Address'));
```

So, from here now i have to update city="USA".

Actual Json:---

```
    {"size":1,
"totalSize":1,
"done":true,
"queryLocator":null,
"entityTypeName":"FlowDefinition",
"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"FlowDefinition","url":"/services/data/v42.0/tooling/sobjects/FlowDefinition/3007F000000LP9xQAG"},
"FullName":"test_flow",
"DeveloperName":"test_flow",
"Metadata":{"activeVersionNumber":null,"description":null,"masterLabel":null,"urls":null}}]}
```

As we can  see the field *activeVersionNumber* is null,so we need to set it as 0 or 1.
The return type of *activeVersionNumber* is **object**.
If i use Json2Apex ,the return type is **Object** but i need to set the integer value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert JSON into equivalent Apex class like what @Shantanu has suggested, the only downside is sometimes we dont know the JSON structure to create Apex classes.

Instead, we can use `deserializeuntype` . deserializeuntype returns us the Map keyValue pair , which we can use on our advantage, and alter the value in map and again serialize it.

```
String input = '{"size":1,"totalSize":1,"done":true,"queryLocator":null,"entityTypeName":"FlowDefinition","records":[{"attributes":{"type":"FlowDefinition","url":"/services/data/v42.0/tooling/sobjects/FlowDefinition/3007F000000LP9xQAG"},"FullName":"test_flow","DeveloperName":"test_flow","Metadata":{"activeVersionNumber":null,"description":null,"masterLabel":null,"urls":null}}]}';

Map<string,object> objmap= (Map<string,object>)json.deserializeUntyped(input );

List<Object> recordsMap =(List<Object>) objmap.get('records');

for(Object obj: recordsMap ){
    Map<String,Object> mapOfrecord = ( Map<String,Object>)obj;
    Map<String,Object> metaDataObject =( Map<String,Object>)  mapOfrecord.get('Metadata'); 
    metaDataObject.put('activeVersionNumber',1);

}


System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(objmap));
```

Output =>

```
  {
  "records" : [ {
    "Metadata" : {
      "urls" : null,
      "masterLabel" : null,
      "description" : null,
      "activeVersionNumber" : 1
    },
    "DeveloperName" : "test_flow",
    "FullName" : "test_flow",
    "attributes" : {
      "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/tooling/sobjects/FlowDefinition/3007F000000LP9xQAG",
      "type" : "FlowDefinition"
    }
  } ],
  "entityTypeName" : "FlowDefinition",
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "done" : true,
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "size" : 1
}
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm

Answer (score 2):

With the use of this [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/), you can convert the JSON to Apex class as follows

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public String FirstName;
    public String LastName;
    public Address Address;

    public class Address {
        public String city;
        public String state;
        public String country;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Now you can assign value easily.

```
JSON2Apex obj = JSON2Apex.parse(response.getbody());
obj.Address.city = 'USA';

System.debug('city='+ obj.Address.city);
```

Comment: ,suppose in the above class inside address class there is one more variable like public Object Activeversionnumber; then how to set this value as 0 or 1; return type is object and we want to set it to integer.